# How do I remove alignment lines in google apps script editor?

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I toggle off alignment lines in google apps script editor? Please see image attached. Thanks in advance.[images shows alignment lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PixJb.png)

Comment: How the lines should look like?

Comment: The only way to remove the lines is use the Classic Editor.  But I would advise against that since that editor will go away some day.

Comment: Go to [Issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%2B) and make a feature request

Comment: Thank you. To answer Yuri's question, the lines are useful and fairly unobtrusive in normal mode but in high contrast mode I find them a bit distracting, esp. for screen shots.